# Assign string if variable is nil and append otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to shorten this code:

```
if a.nil?
  a = "foo"
else
  a << "foo"
end
```

`a` is either `nil` or a string.

I have already tried `a ||= "foo"` and `a += "foo"` but these don't work if `a` is `nil`.

Comment: `a = "foo"` what's all that you need.

Comment: no! I want concat string. not replace!

Comment: a can be nil or string! 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39162660/5118204
this answer is what i need! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nil.to_s` is equals to `''` so you could write

```
a = a.to_s + 'foo'
```

or, an alternative

```
a = "#{a}foo"
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for support

Comment: Don't `rescue` if you don't have to. A better alternative is `a = "#{a}foo"`.

Answer (score 5):

It might be irrelevant in your case, but there's a difference between `a +=` and `a <<`.

`+=` assigns a new string to `a`, leaving the old one unchanged:

```
a = 'abc'
b = a

a += 'foo'

a #=> "abcfoo"   # <- a refers to the new string object
b #=> "foo"      # <- b still refers to the original string
```

This is because [`String#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-2B) returns a *new* string. `a += 'foo'` is equivalent to `a = a + 'foo'`.

[`String#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) on the other hand *modifies* the existing string, it doesn't create a new one:

```
a = 'abc'
b = a

a << 'foo'

a #=> "abcfoo"
b #=> "abcfoo"   # <- both changed, because a and b refer to the same object
```

So, in order to shorten your code without changing its behavior, you could use:

```
(a ||= '') << 'foo'
```

`a ||= ''` assigns an empty string to `a` if `a` is `nil`. Then `<< 'foo'` appends `'foo'` to `a`.

Comment: Thanks for support!

Answer (score 0):

write like below:

```
a = a.nil? ? (a.to_s + 'foo') : 'foo'
```

Comment: This is referred to as Ruby's ternary operator.

Comment: Something strange in this condition. The same result gives this `a = 'foo'`.

Comment: but if a = "foo" before your code, it's not true. i want Concat string, not replace! .

Comment: This will assign the string conditionally not concat the string

Comment: It should be the other way round: `a = a.nil? ? 'foo' : a.to_s + 'foo'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine 2 strings, where any one of them may be `nil`, you could do:

```rb
a.nil? ? a = (b || '') : a << (b || '')
```

This works even if `a`, `b` or both are `nil`.

This is also by far faster than alternative methods, even though the syntax is somewhat ugly.

**Benchmark:**

```rb
require 'benchmark'

n = 50_000_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("compact.reduce(:+)")   { n.times { a = nil; b = 'foo'; a = [a, b].compact.reduce(:+) } }
  x.report("string interpolation") { n.times { a = nil; b = 'foo'; a = "#{a}#{b}" } }
  x.report("to_s")                 { n.times { a = nil; b = 'foo'; a = a.to_s + b.to_s } }
  x.report("(x || '') +")          { n.times { a = nil; b = 'foo'; a = (a || '') + b } }
  x.report("(x || '') <<")         { n.times { a = nil; b = 'foo'; a = (a || '') << b } } # will throw an exception if used with `frozen_string_literal: true`
  x.report("ternary")              { n.times { a = nil; b = 'foo'; a.nil? ? a = (b || '') : a << (b || '') } }
end
```

**Results:**

```rb
                      user       system     total       real
compact.reduce(:+)    6.677367   0.000000   6.677367 (  6.677337)
string interpolation  7.983451   0.000000   7.983451 (  7.983440)
to_s                  7.067699   0.000000   7.067699 (  7.067702)
(x || '') +           5.130624   0.000000   5.130624 (  5.130585)
(x || '') <<          4.809965   0.000000   4.809965 (  4.809978)
ternary               3.300871   0.000000   3.300871 (  3.300838)
```